# Is every complex rational algebraic variety simply connected for the Euclidean topology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is it true that every quasi-projective rational irreducible algebraic  complex variety is simply connected for the Euclidean topology?

Of course, this is false if we replace "complex" with "real" or if we forget "rational".

Comment: Actually you *did* forget "rational".

Comment: Thx.... I did not in the title, but after, yes.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, isn't $\mathbb{P}^1\backslash\{0,\infty\}$ a counterexample?

Comment: It's also false for singular rational varieties (e.g. for a nodal cubic). In the positive direction: a nonsingular rational projective variety is simply connected.

Comment: Donu's nice comment generalizes to rationally connected varieties, Prop. 6.14 in  http://www.personal.psu.edu/jwh6013/Research/RationalConnectivity.pdf  and Julian Rosen's neat example can be crossed with projective space to yield higher dimensional examples.  such as a quadric surface minus two disjoint lines.  This suggests many examples may exist by removing a disconnected divisor from a projective rational variety.

Comment: For every connected semisimple group $G$ over $\mathbf{C}$ (which is rational, via the open cell), the theory of maximal compact subgroups implies that $\pi_1(G(\mathbf{C}))$ coincides with the "fundamental group" of $G$ in the sense of semisimple algebraic groups (using root lattice and weight lattice). Hence, that $\pi_1$ is nontrivial whenever $G$ is not "simply connected in the sense of algebraic groups"; e.g., PGL$_n(\mathbf{C})$ ($n \ge 2$) and ${\rm{SO}}_n(\mathbf{C})$ ($n\ge 3$) are counterexamples. Rosen's counterexample is SO$_2(\mathbf{C})$ by another name.

Comment: Pet peeve: "rational connectivity" should be "rational connectedness".  For topological spaces, the nouns are "connectedness", "path connectedness", "arc connectedness", etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I want to mention the positive direction.  Let $X$ be a smooth, projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$, resp. over an algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic.  Let $Z\subset X$ be a proper closed subset.  If $X$ is (separably) rationally connected and if $Z$ has codimension $\geq 2$ in $X$, then $X\setminus Z$ is simply connected for the Euclidean topology, resp. the algebraic fundamental group is trivial.  This was first proved by Campana over $\mathbb{C}$: there is an excellent explanation in Debarre's book, "Higher dimensional algebraic geometry".  There is another proof by Kollár that extends to positive characteristic: there is an excellent explanation in one of Debarre's Bourbaki seminars.

One might hope to drop the hypothesis that $Z$ has codimension $2$ if we assume that every general pair of points of $X\setminus Z$ is connected by a rational curve completely contained in $X\setminus Z$.  Unfortunately there are many counterexamples, such as the smooth locus of the singular cubic surface with equation $xyz-w^3=0$.  What is true is that the fundamental group is finite.  However, it is quite open to understand the fundamental group of the smooth locus of $\mathbb{Q}$-log-Fano varieties, cf. work of Chenyang Xu, Zhiyu Tian, etc.